# JAVAFX - Wait For TitledPane Content Is Expanded

Tags: java, javafx, nodes, controls

I want to update UI after titledpane's content is expanded so I can catch the newest titledpane's height as the reference in updating the UI. I tried the following but it still fire things up too early.

```
myTitledPane.expandedProperty().addListener((ob)->{
     if(myTitledPane.isExpanded()){
       // update ui
          methodToUpdateUI();
     }
});
```

The code above don't want to make `methodToUpdateUI()` waiting for the titledpane to expand before start running.

Is there  a way to make the method `methodToUpdateUI()` waiting for titledpane to expand before running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*JavaFX—Scroll TitledPane To ViewPort Area When Expanded*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45559696/230513) & this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13156896/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
myTitledPane.expandedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue) {
            //
        }
    });
```